# MySQL select query based on month span

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

Is it possible to select a timestamp in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS` using MySQL over a predefined monthly span?

Basically I would like the query to select all rows from the current date `now()` to a predefined month (e.g January).

So as an example, if the current date is the 25th June 2011 - the MySQL should select all rows from the current date, back to the 1st January 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ... From MyTable
Where SomeDateField Between MakeDate(Year(Now()),1) and Now()
```

is a one way.

if you want a bit more leeway on how far you go back then instead of Makedate

use something like Concat(Cast (Year(Now) As VarChar(4)),'-01-01')

if you build  a string in the Form YYYY-MM-DD it will auto convert to the date.

Comment: Hi @Tony Hopkinson May I ask, what does the 1 represent?

Comment: 1 as in day 1 of the year, works in your exmple don't use it for say 6 months ago ,as you'll have to messa bouyt with leaop years and such

Answer (score 1):

basically you run a statement like so:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE your_date_column >= '2011-01-01 00-00-00' AND your_date_column <= '2011-06-25 00-00-00'
```

this should return all row with the date less than june 25, 2011.  i hope this helps.